# how to know the number of line being read now

Tags: c, string

last time i asked about signals in a project i had, and your aid was quite helpful. i only have one problem stuck. i want to read a file (must be large text file) and count the occurrences of some words. well this isn't a problem anymore
 but whenever i invoke the SIGSTP (ctrl+Z) the program should display the line number it's reading now, how is that possible.
i know how to count the number of lines of the whole text, so if i invoke it at a certain time, the returned number will be the overall line numbers, or the line being read

Comment: Show us the code. And don't forget to accept the answer to your previous question (and this one).

Comment: counting the overall number was pretty simple, lines=1; if(c=='\n') ++lines; i kept incrementing till the end of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register for the specific signal using the signal system call:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);
sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

For example:

```
void signal_handler(int signal) 
{
    //display line number
}

signal(SIGSTP, signal_handler);
```

The signal will interrupt your current code chain which means that the signal handler can be called during your reading on the file.
If you use a global variable to store the line you are reading, then this return the latest called value.

Comment: thanks alot, this is exactly what i was asking about

Comment: if this is what you were asking for, mark this as the answer and give credit where due

Answer (score 1):

Maintain a global integer counter which is the line number of the line being read. Increment each time you read a line (or if you are not reading by the line, each time you hit a `\n`). Print this in your signal handler.

Note that whilst the above will work, technically speaking it is not safe to print anything within a signal handler (see `man -s7 signal` to see a list of safe things you can do) using `printf` or other buffered I/O, so technically speaking you should use `write` or similar, doing the format conversion yourself.